# Java API for Oculus Rift?

Tags: java, oculus, virtual-reality

I'm trying to get familiar with development with Oculus Rift. I have hand-on experiences in Java-based languages (Java and Android), and would rather code in Java than C/C++ or C#. I was wondering if there is any stable Java API or wrapper to use for Virtual Reality development using Oculus Rift?

Comment: Yes, I knew that. I'm not sure if it is under development or not. I wanted to see if there are any other options as well.

Comment: LibOVR bindings have been added to [LWJGL 3](https://www.lwjgl.org/) starting with LibOVR version 0.8. Bindings for LibOVR 1.3 have been released just yesterday. Until the next major release they are available in the [nightly release](https://www.lwjgl.org/download).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JOVR](https://github.com/jherico/jovr) is a JNA based wrapper for the Oculus SDK, currently supporting the 0.7 SDK (which is compatible with the current 0.8 runtime) and is available on Maven as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.saintandreas</groupId>
  <artifactId>jovr</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, there is the [JRift](https://github.com/mabrowning/JRift) project, which is more up to date and uses JNI I believe.

Comment: JOVR seems promising. Have you ever used it yourself? I was wondering if I get very noticeable decreased performance or lag if I use it?

Comment: I wrote it.  While JNA has somewhat lower performance than JNA, the overhead of the function calls to the Oculus is negligible compared to the frame time.  In other words, if there's lag or judder, it's most likely from the rendering code, not from the JOVR interface.

Comment: Just two quick questions. I'm new to Oculus so sorry if it sounds stupid: 1) can I use the wrapper (say JOVR) for the Android SDK of Oculus? 2) Can I use it for any HMDs, like Samsung Gear? Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use it for Android or GearVR.  it's strictly a Java binding for the PC SDK.